# CSS Header with Link Buttons

Tags: html, css

I have created a header + a login and a signup buttons. Here is my issue, if I do not add the login and signup button under the header class, the buttons will not show up. However, by adding the buttons under the header class the css formatting for the text is defaulting to the header css. I have tried everything to get the buttons to float right and show up outside of the header class but nothing is working.

**Issues inside Header Class** - Text color is #39C instead of black. In Chrome or Firefox the hover color shows but the text color never turns white.

**Issues outside Header Class** - The buttons just do not show up. I thought it had something to do with the z-index but nothing worked when I attempted to make changes.

Thanks for any help!

Header and button CSS

```
.header { position: absolute; height: 45px; right: 0; top: 0; left: 0; }

.mtstyle { text-align: center; margin-top: 5px; margin-left:15px; }

.mtlstyle a:link, a:visited, a:active { color: #3399CC; }

.mtlstyle a:link, a:visited, a:active { text-decoration: none; }

.tcard { box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0,   
   0, 0.19); margin-left: -15px; padding: 15px; }

.btna { padding: 7px 16px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none;  
   display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; margin: -53px 10px 30px; cursor: 
   pointer; float:right; }

.btn1 { /* Login */ background-color: white; color: black; border: 0px solid 
   #000; font-size: 14px }

.btn2 { /* Signup */ background-color: white; border: 3px solid #39C; color:
  black; font-size: 14px; hover-background: gray; }

.btn2:hover { background-color: #39C; color: white; }
```

Here is the HTML

```
<!--Title-->
   <div class="header">
   <div class="mtstyle">
   <div class="mtlstyle">
   <div class="tcard">
   <h1><a href="index.php">Page Title</a></h1> 

<!--Login-->
   <a class="btna btn2" href="login.php">Signup</a>
   <a class="btna btn1" href="login.php">Login</a>
     </div>
      </div>
        </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is css specificty rules.  Smashing magazine has a good article on the rules: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/.  For some reason, it's asking for a login, but you can hit cancel and still get there.

If you want to override the styles applied with:

```
.mtlstyle a:link,
.mtlstyle a:visited,
.mtlstyle a:active {
  color: #3399CC;
}
```

you need to be more specific.  Changing your selector to

```
a.btn1:link,
a.btn1:visited,
a.btn1:visited {
  /* Login */
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 0px solid #000;
  font-size: 14px
}
```

will make you more specific and that rule will apply for the login button.

https://jsfiddle.net/qg569f35/3/

Comment: Thank you, this fix my issue. Also, thanks for the article.